# Can the PowerQuery SDK be used to build a java custom connector?

Tags: java, powerbi, powerquery

We are trying to get data from HFM (Oracle Hyperion Financial Management) datasource, but unfortunately thats not an option (yet) in powerbi. So we have decided to look into building a custom connector using HFM API's. the problem is that HFM API's are java based, and based on my research so far, im only seeing PowerQuery SDK c# based samples.

Is a java custom connector not possible then? Is the PowerQuery SDK only limited for integration with C#/PowerShell?

Related thread:[Is there any way to invoke PowerQuery/M outside of Excel or PowerBI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432718/is-there-any-way-to-invoke-powerquery-m-outside-of-excel-or-powerbi/54898353#54898353)

Comment: Well, I think that if you can expose the data you want via RESTful Web Services in java, then it would be possible to consume them with Power Query.

Comment: @Dreekun so you mean we would have a standalone java program/script that would first fetch the data and then we pass that data to the actual custom connector file that would be written in PowerQuery?

Comment: @Dreekun just updated my manager/team. apparently HFM doesnt have REST API's :/

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Custom Connectors are just programmed calls to Restful Web Services, iirc. If you build them it should work.

Comment: @Dreekun i see, thanks for the info!

Comment: How can we get the java api endpoint?

Comment: @syamkumarc it's been a while but I remember there was some documentation available on this on Oracle