# Standalone Power Query tool

Tags: powerquery

I would very much like to implement Power Query queries without having to have Power Bi or Excel, ideally, having queries run frequently in the background, saving results to disk in an apporpriate format.

Does Microsoft offer such a tool? If not, what would be a solution?

Comment: See https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is a [Power BI dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-introduction-self-service) or a [Power Automate flow](https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/).

Beyond that, you're essentially looking for database functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I hit while searching myself.

I found PowerQueryNet

https://github.com/gsimardnet/PowerQueryNet/blob/master/README.md

Also see these

[Is there any way to invoke PowerQuery/M outside of Excel or PowerBI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432718/is-there-any-way-to-invoke-powerquery-m-outside-of-excel-or-powerbi)

And about the SDK

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/02/12/running-m-queries-in-visual-studio-with-the-power-query-sdk/